# Webrtc conference call recording using recordrtc

Tags: angular, webrtc, recordrtc

I'm building new application using Angular 7 and WebRTC,and I use recordRTC.js to recording (audio&video) my issue is when I record multiple streams only audio of first stream is recorded.

```
public addStreamToRecorder(stream: MediaStream) 
{

  if (!this.recorder) 
     {
      this.recorder = RecordRTC([stream],{type: "video"});
      this.recorder.startRecording();
     } 
  else 
     {
      this.recorder.getInternalRecorder().addStreams([stream]);
     }
 }
```

after investigation  i found that appendStreams function in reocrdrtc not mix audios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue by updating  appendStreams  function in recordRTC with latest version in i got it from MultiStreamRecorder (https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder)

replace  appendStreams  in recordRTC with

```
this.appendStreams = function (streams) {
    if (!streams) {
        throw 'First parameter is required.';
    }

    if (!(streams instanceof Array)) {
        streams = [streams];
    }

    arrayOfMediaStreams.concat(streams);
    streams.forEach(stream => {
        if (stream.getTracks().filter(function (t) {
            return t.kind === 'video';
        }).length) {
            var video = getVideo(stream);
            video.stream = stream;
            videos.push(video);
        }

        if (stream.getTracks().filter(function (t) {
            return t.kind === 'audio';
        }).length && this.audioContext) {
            var audioSource = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            audioSource.connect(this.audioDestination);
            self.audioSources.push(audioSource);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: can you share more details. I am not clear about audioContext, audioDestination, audioSources . It will be helpful if you share more detailed code.